# Installing FreeBSD/mfsBSD remotely? whats up with the config?

Tags: linux, installation, freebsd, remote-installation

I have a ubuntu box which I currently cannot get to since its across the continent.

I need to install FreeBSD on it and it hopeless to guide onsite people through this.
I looked around and found [this.](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/remote-install/index.html) But it seems to be kind of out of date.

I looked at the latest mfsbsd scripts, but in the conf/ dir there seem to be duplicate enties.
Seemingly all settings in the conf files are repeated in loader.conf.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The settings in `loader.conf` become part of the kernel environment.
Note that in the [ditribution](https://github.com/mmatuska/mfsbsd/blob/master/conf/loader.conf.sample), all those variables are commented out.

The `mfsbsd` script queries those variables and if set uses them to update some configuration files.

It is a way to put most of the necessary changes for a custom mfsbsd image in a single file.